# Would like to draw something similar to confusionMatrix created by ClassifierMeasurements

Tags: plotting, matrix

[image: ConfusionMatrix]

How do I show the values in each box?
I know how to add the labels.

Answer (score 9):

```
MatrixPlot[{{14789, 482}, {446, 202}},
 Epilog -> {
   Text[14789, {1/2, 3/2}],
   Text[  482, {3/2, 3/2}],
   Text[  446, {1/2, 1/2}],
   Text[  202, {3/2, 1/2}]}]
```

[image]

This generalizes (for quadratic matrices) to

```
m = {{14789, 482, 100}, {446, 202, 200}, {1, 2, 3}};

t = 
 Transpose@Map[Flatten, {#, Reverse@Transpose@#} &
  [Table[Range[1, 2 # - 1, 2], {#}]] &[Length@m]]/2
```

[image]

```
MatrixPlot[m, Epilog -> Text @@@ Transpose[{Catenate@m, t}]]
```

[image]

Adding labels

```
m = {{14789, 482}, {446, 202}};

t = 
 Transpose@Map[Flatten, {#, Reverse@Transpose@#} &
  [Table[Range[1, 2 # - 1, 2], {#}]] &[Length@m]]/2;

p =
  MatrixPlot[m,
   Epilog -> Text @@@ Transpose[{Catenate@m, t}],
   FrameTicks -> {
     {{1, "Left1"}, {2, "Left2"}},
     {{1, "Bottom1"}, {2, "Bottom2"}},
     {{1, "Right1"}, {2, "Right2"}},
     {{1, "Top1"}, {2, "Top2"}}},
   ImageSize -> Medium];

Column[{
  Row[{Rotate["actual class", 90 Degree], Spacer@15, p}],
  Spacer@5, "predicted class"}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: Good start, but what about the frame labels?

Comment: "I know how to add the labels" - from the question