# Create ClassifierFunction

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a way to create my own [ClassifierFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierFunction.html)?  I would like to combine predictions from multiple independent classifiers into a single ensemble ClassifierFunction and be able to use things like [ClassifierMeasurments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierMeasurements.html) etc.  Afaik, it seems like the only way to get a ClassifierFunction is via [Classify](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) or [NetTrain](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrain.html) family of functions.

Comment: +1 from me. It's possible to combine classifiers/predictors. But this is undocumented functionality. I have decided to open the new [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133282/classify-predict-ensemble-of-classifiers-predictors) because your should be rewritten completely.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev, why should my question be rewritten completely?

Comment: Your question is unclear on the first sight and was downvoted by someone. I thought to modify your text, add code and images. But what if I am wrong and your original question is _a little different_. For example, I ensemble my models this way: `c1=Classify[...];c2=Classify[...];ensemble[x_]:=(c1[x]+c2[x])/2`. Simple average or weighted average. You can create ConfusionMatrix. See this [question and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103719/would-like-to-draw-something-similar-to-confusionmatrix-created-by-classifiermea) + `Riffle[ensemble[x],y]//Partition[#,2]&//Tally`

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev I'm not sure my question could be more clear.  Thanks for your code snippet but, I'm not interested in generating confusion matrices. Also, `ensemble[x_]:=(c1[x]+c2[x]‌​)/2` does not generate a ClassifierFunction and therefore can not be used as input  to  `ClassifierMeasurements`.

Comment: Abel, I have found [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135246/23402)!

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Thanks, much appreciated!