# Classify / Predict: ensemble of classifiers / predictors

Tags: machine-learning, undocumented

Mathematica has undocumented functionality of combination classifiers / predictors in ensemble. How to get access to this functionality?

```
SeedRandom[1];
X = Table[
   Join[
    ToString /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1],
    RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4],
    RandomSample[{"A", "B", "C"}, 2]
    ],
   {1000}
   ];
Y = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 1000];
```

```
c = Classify[X -> Y]
```

[image]

```
ClassifierInformation[c]
```

[image]

```
ClassifierMeasurements[c, X -> Y, "ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133246/create-classifierfunction?noredirect=1&lq=1) I posted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
c1 = Classify[X -> Y, Method -> "LogisticRegression"]
c2 = Classify[X -> Y, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]

c = MachineLearning`PackageScope`CombinePredictors[{c1, c2}]

ClassifierInformation[c]
```

[image]

```
p1 = Predict[X -> Y, Method -> "LinearRegression"]
p2 = Predict[X -> Y, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]

p = MachineLearning`PackageScope`CombinePredictors[{p1, p2}]

PredictorInformation[p]
```

[image]

Comment: Great (+1) -- do you think you can find how to do a weighted combination of the classifiers?

Comment: @AntonAntonov I am not sure. Right now Combiner can be only 'Geometric". `GeneralUtilities\`PrintDefinitions@MachineLearning\`PackageScope\`CombinePredictors`

Comment: What about 11.3? It doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @swish Yes, it stopped work in V11.2. Function was renamed to `Combiner`. But it doesn't work the old way. During exploration I found that `Classify` has the new method `Combination`. But I don't know what is wrong: `Classify[X -> Y, Method -> {"Combination", "Methods" -> {"LogisticRegression", "NearestNeighbors"}, "CombinerMethod" -> "Geometric"}, "DirectTraining" -> True]` See `GeneralUtilities\`PrintDefinitions@MachineLearning\`PackageScope\`TrainPredictor`

Comment: How to combine two trained models of Classify in 13.1 or 13.2?

Comment: Hello @HyperGroups. Take a look at `Classify[{0 -> 0, 1 -> 1}, Method -> "Combination"]` and `GeneralUtilities\`PrintDefinitions@MachineLearning\`PackageScope\`TrainModel` ("Combination"). I was unable to run it.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev seems not OK, tested on 13.3   `ClassifierFunction::mlincfttp: Incompatible variable type (NumericalVector) and variable value (Method->{Combination,Methods->{LogisticRegression,LogisticRegression}}).`

Answer (score 8):

The question formulation asks for access to the internals of `Classify` in order to get the ensembles, but there is way to make ensembles of classifiers (i.e. `ClassifierFunction[___]` functions) through the argument "Probabilities" -- see the (short) package [ClassifierEnsembles.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/ClassifierEnsembles.m).

Very detailed explanations for using and evaluating classifier ensembles made with that package are given in:

- [ROC for classifier ensembles, bootstrapping, damaging, and interpolation](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/944004) (at community.wolfram.com), or
- [the same article at WordPress](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/roc-for-classifier-ensembles-bootstrapping-damaging-and-interpolation/) (loads faster).

Here is an image of ROC curves for comparing the performance of a classifier ensemble with its individual classifiers:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, that.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you, good to hear.

Comment: Anton, good answer! +1 here and in the Wolfram Community. But I can not accept your answer because, as you have noted, my question is about the internals of `Classify`. With Spelunking I have read `Classify` code but didn't understand how to call `Combiner`-function directly.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Thank you for your note! I understand your perspective. I posted this answer because with that package I am using the internals of `Classify` indirectly through "Probabilities".

Comment: I have found solution!

Comment: really good answer/article !

Comment: @AbelBrown Thank you, good to hear.

Comment: @AntonAntonov, as always, very good answer! Congratulations!! +1

Comment: @Rod thanks, good to hear!